# iOS 10, Xcode 8 Simulator Won't Launch

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, xcode8

When I try to run my iOS app in the simulator, I get this error: Unable to lookup service com.apple.CoreSimulator.host_support: 0x3

The app runs just fine when I deploy to my phone.

I am on macOS 10.12.2, Xcode 8.2.1, Simulator 10.0

I have already tried restarting Xcode, cleaning and cleaning the build directory. It does not just happen with one particular project.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: How did you solve it?